# GIT: Rease local master with local branch

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

I have local branch (development) but I want merge my changes to master.

I tried the following:

form my development branch:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

But what happened my development branch lost my changes and I had to reset my development branch.

How can I rebase my master branch with development branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on your development branch (let's say it's called `dev`):

```
git checkout dev
```

And you rebase it on the *remote* `master` branch:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

This should result your changes on top of the latest change in `origin/master`.  Note that depending on your local activity, `master` may not have the same content as `origin/master` so make sure you are rebasing on top of the correct branch.

This shouldn't cause any changes to be *lost*, although depending on the changes involved it can result in conflicts that need to be resolved manually.

If you aren't sure you're doing the right thing, remember that you can always test things out on a new branch.  E.g., to checkout a new branch named `testbranch` that is identical to your `dev` branch:

```
git checkout -b testbranch dev
```

Now you can play with `rebase` without making any changes to your `dev` branch.

Comment: Is it better to do a git pull on master and rebase dev branch to master than origin/master?

```
# 1. git checkout master
# 2. git pull
# 3. git checkout dev
# 4. git rebase master
```

Comment: There's really no difference between `git checkout master; git pull; git checkout mybranch; git rebase master` and `git remote update; git rebase origin/master` (assuming you were already on `mybranch`).  Maybe sometimes you want your local `master` branch to be different from the upstream `master` branch. It really depends on your own particular requirements.